# R. T test for two groups that are part of different categories in the same data set?

Tags: r

I have a final lab and am trying to run a T-test to see if there is a significant difference between salary if you major in a STEM major vs a Humanity major vs a Social Science major. I have each major labeled as either SS, S, or H in one column. Is there a way I could compare each group easily? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Could you include your data and what code you have so far?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H5p8Oks2zrE-Xgm9Yv4Um635ellju6xc/view?usp=sharing Here is the dataset. I just want to compare the starting salary of Humanity majors vs the starting salary of STEM majors

Comment: Need access to get to the data. One of the things you can do is edit the original question and post a part of the data in the question. The same with posting syntax. The idea is for anyone answering the question to see what you see and reproduce it to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the pairwise t-test functionality from here [Pairwise T Test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/pairwise.t.test). I personally like to use the Bonferroni correction since it is conservative (it simply divides the p-thresholds by number of comparisons).

You also probably want to graph your output by using something like

```
dat_grouped <- dat %>% group_by(Major) %>% summarise(Mean_Salary = mean(Salary), SD_Salary = sd(Salary), N= n())
    ggplot(data = dat_grouped, aes(x=Major, y = Mean_Salary )) + 
    geom_col() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin =Mean_Salary -1.96*SD_Salary , ymax = Mean_Salary +1.96*SD_Salary), width = 0.25)
```

Comment: Thanks. The link helps alot.